# Require JS files from bower_components by saying "require('library')" possible?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, bower

I'm new to RequireJS and it seems it might not actually be possible but I'll still go ahead and ask away in case I'm missing something.

In the docs it says..

> This setup assumes you keep all your JavaScript files in a "scripts" directory in your project.
>
> - project-directory/
>
>   - project.html
>   - scripts/
>
>     - main.js
>     - helper/
>
>       - util.js

But what if I have to require files from my bower installed files in bower_components:

> - project-directory/
>
>   - bower_components/
>
>     - jquery-mousewheel
>
>       - jquery.mousewheel.js
>     - lodash
>
>       - dist
>
>         - lodash.js

As you see, not all libraries have the same directory hierarchy and naming convention.

So I was wondering is there a simple way to require these bower libraries without actually knowing where their main files are, maybe by simply saying

```
require('jquery-mousewheel');
require('loadash');
```

?

Comment: If you use Grunt as part of a build process, this plugin might be of interest to you: https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-bower-requirejs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

setup your requirejs config to use paths

```
requirejs.config({
    // ... config ...
    paths: {
        jquery-mousewheel: 'bower_components/jquery-mousewheel/jquery.mousewheel',
        loadash: 'bower_components/lodash/dist/lodash' 
    }
    // ... config ...
});
```

[documentation for reference](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-paths)

Comment: thanks. I see. So no way around to actually filling in those paths manually atleast somewhere huh. Well, thanks anyways!

Comment: Well, they don't need to be file-exact paths, do they? Can't you reduce the path configuration so that anything starting with "lodash" refers to a certain directory?

Comment: @Katana314 you can make the paths a little cleaner by using the `baseUrl` option

Answer (score 3):

I think [this is a better solution](http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/#requirejs)...

```
requirejs.config({
  baseUrl: 'bower_components/',
  paths: { // path to your app
    app: '../'
  }
});

requirejs( [
  'imagesloaded/imagesloaded',
  'app/my-component.js'
], function( imagesLoaded, myComp ) { 
  imagesLoaded( '#container', function() { ... });
});
```

Comment: Why is this "better"?

Comment: The the use of `baseUrl`